# laptop with ubuntu logo on it?

Tags: laptop, logo

Ok, this might be a little silly.

I want to buy a new laptop and I **really really want one with the ubuntu logo on the back of it**. Not a sticker or anything, I want it to be part of the casing - like Apple or Dell or whatever.

I googled around but I couldn't find anyting besides people [daydreaming and making cool pictures](http://www.bestubuntu.com/ubuntu-laptop-concept.html), and I want a practical answer. Is there **any percievable way** to get this (also, without it costing a fortune)? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Buy a metal cased laptop, and bring it to some place, where they can do Laser engraving on the case. Though I'm sure that's not exactly cheap either.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you will get to a manufactured Ubuntu logo, is the System76 logo on the laptops from them. https://system76.com/laptops/

Ubuntu is not a hardware manufacturer and therefore no "cases" are made for it. Apple and Dell are hardware manufacturers so they can put their own logo on it.

To get an actual Ubuntu logo ingraved in your current laptop, would be the only way to get this done.

Comment: I know about system76. I'm not looking for ubuntu pre-installed laptops. Maybe I should have mentioned that. I also know canonical is not a hardware manufactor, but I don't get why that prevents anyone else doing it for them

Comment: @yuvi Supply And Demand, would be my guess. Probably not that many have requested it yet.

Comment: I'm thinking the Ubuntu phone kickstarter proved otherwise. Also, I can't be the only one who wants to see canonical hardware, right?

Comment: @yuvi Start a kickstarter for this, and see how big a demand there is for it? :)

Comment: I just might =P

Comment: @yuvi Keep in mind that the Ubuntu logo is a trademark, so you would need to obtain permission from Canonical first. Working for an Ubuntu OEM (System76), it's a bit more involved than you may be expecting.

Comment: @IanSantopietro I was half joking actually, I don't see myself getting into that sort of thing. However, it would be interesting to see how much response such a campaign will garner (I'm pretty sure this is a missed market on Canonical's part, but whatever, that's just me)